# Jquery append then update element id

Tags: javascript, jquery, append

https://jsfiddle.net/codenoob/cavrnyv0/6/

please see jsfiddle.

I have a button that append a new row to the table. then I want to update the id for the newly added row so each row is unique. however the squence is wrong.

for example. I expect getting

```
original
newrow 1
newrow 2
newrow 3
```

instead I get

```
newrow 1
newrow 2
newrow 3
original
```

if you check element on developer tool. you will notice. It is not appending before original, but it is renaming the original to be newrow1.

what did I do wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use `html()` for cloning - jquery comes with a clone feature that is much more efficient.

Also, you always want to make as many changes to a DOM node as you can *before* inserting it into the DOM. In this case, you want to set the ID of the new select box before you attach the new row. The reason is because once a DOM node has been inserted (eg, you can see it in the page), every change causes it to be rerendered - which is just inefficient.

Take a look at this updated fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/cavrnyv0/8/

Comment: this look promising I will try it out. did not know about the clone feature.